# When storing text on a USB drive, how do I make cat not hang?

Tags: text-processing, usb-drive, cat, printf, head

> Warning: I used these commands on a drive that had nothing on it (`/dev/sdb`). Do not attempt this on a drive with anything important on it.

I was experimenting some, and I discovered that the following works:

```bsh
$ printf 'hi\n' | sudo tee /dev/sdb
hi
$ sudo head -n 1 /dev/sdb
hi
$
```

Neat. Here's where I'm confused. I tried it again with `cat` (the first command is the same, I replaced the second one with `sudo cat /dev/sdb`. It printed `hi`, followed by a newline, and hung. Doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> didn't work to stop it. Bummer.

I reasoned that perhaps `cat` wanted a null (`\0`) character at the end. So I tried again (`printf 'hi\n\0' | sudo tee /dev/sdb`), and `head` worked as before, but `cat` still hung. How can I get `cat` to not hang when writing directly to a USB drive? *I'm not asking if this is a good idea (it isn't). I'm well aware I could just format the drive and use a text file, but I'm curious why this didn't work as expected.*

I'm using Debian 11, with a 2 GB flash drive (`/dev/sdb`).

Comment: `how do I make cat not hang?` made me think of https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hang+in+there+baby&iax=images&ia=images  ... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf 'hi\n' | sudo tee /dev/sdb
```

copies the standard input (from the pipe) to standard output and to `/dev/sdb`

```
printf 'hi\n' | sudo cat /dev/sdb
```

copies `/dev/sdb` to standard output. The output from the pipe is not read by `cat`.

So `cat` does not hang, it is copying the whole contents of the disk to the terminal, and that takes a while. The pipe doesn't change anything for cat, since the first parameter tells it `/dev/sdb` is the input.